# ¿Qué o cómo se lee una variable seguido con dos signos de interrogación y comillas simples?

Tags: php7

Tengo un formulario en laravel y tengo el siguiente campo así:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">Teléfono (Whastapp):</label>
    <input type="tel" wire:model="phone" class="form-control" id="taskTitle">{{{ 
     $phone ?? '' }}}</input> @error('phone') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> 
     @enderror
</div>
```

Al momento de agregar algún dato al campo vacio se muestra debajo del campo lo que uno escribe pero mi duda es qué o cómo se interpreta lo siguiente:

```
{{{ $phone ?? '' }}}
```

¿Por qué tiene tres {}?

Los signos de interrogación (?) ¿Por qué son dos? y ¿qué significan?

¿Las comillas simples para que son?

Comment: jajajaj de las llave si me equivoque solamente son dos, pero lo demás $variable ?? '' no entiendo esa parte de los signos de interrogación y las comillas simples

Comment: Los de los signos de {{}} ya lo entendi estaba mal, pero no entiendo los ?? y ñps dos ''